# Planeswalker Infinite Ultimate Combo

Tags: magic-the-gathering, puzzles

Infinite combos in Magic are awesome (if you're a Johnny).  Planeswalker ultimate abilities are awesome (if you're a Timmy).  Combining the two would be even more awesome.  Then you could have a billion emblems from [Chandra, Torch of Defiance](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChandra%2c%20Torch%20of%20Defiance%5d), [Teferi, Hero of Dominaria](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeferi%2c%20Hero%20of%20Dominaria%5d), or [Kiora, the Crashing Wave](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKiora%2c%20the%20Crashing%20Wave%5d).  Because dealing a billion damage isn't as cool as doing it every time you cast a spell.  And getting a billion krakens isn't as cool as getting them every turn.

What's the fewest number of cards (besides the planeswalker) that allows you to activate a planeswalker's ultimate ability an arbitrary number of times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest combo in general is 3 cards: [Gilder Bairn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGilder%20Bairn%5d), [Banishing Knack](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBanishing%20Knack%5d), and [Gemstone Array](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGemstone%20Array%5d) works for all planeswalkers.

---

## Explanation

There are 3 card combos around the [The Chain Veil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThe%20Chain%20Veil%5d) (all you need to add is infinite mana and artifact untapping, such [Astral Cornucopia](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAstral%20Cornucopia%5d) with 4 counters and [Filigree Sages](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFiligree%20Sages%5d), or the combo suggested by [@Andrew](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/43840/9999)).  However, these combos only work for planeswalkers with a "+x" ability that won't kill either you or your opponent in the process of using them repeatedly, so it's incompatible with planeswalkers like [Chandra, Bold Pyromancer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChandra%2c%20Bold%20Pyromancer%5d), [Sarkhan the Mad](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSarkhan%20the%20Mad%5d), and [Jace Beleren](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJace%20Beleren%5d).

[Gilder Bairn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGilder%20Bairn%5d), [Banishing Knack](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBanishing%20Knack%5d), and a [Gemstone Array](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGemstone%20Array%5d) works for all planeswalkers.  Gilder Bairn creates infinite mana with Gemstone Array (provided you have a way to tap the Bairn) and can also pump a planeswalker to have enough counters to use its ultimate the turn it enters the battlefield.  Banishing Knack provides both a way to tap the Bairn and a way to bounce and replay the planeswalker, which causes it to be a new object and thus resets the count on how many times it has used a loyalty ability this turn.  In order for this to work, you need sufficient starting counters on the Gemstone Array and some cheap permanent you can cast repeatedly to bounce with the Bairn while building up infinite mana on the Gemstone Array, noting that the planeswalker you plan to play can be this permanent.  The number of starting counters you need on the array to combo off is 7 + [the cost of your cheapest non-land permanent].

---

## Special Cases

There are fewer-card combos with particular planeswalkers, the clear winner of which is 1 card plus the planeswalker: [Doubling Season](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDoubling%20Season%5d) with [Jace, Cunning Castaway](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJace%2c%20Cunning%20Castaway%5d).

You can also do this in Commander with 2 cards if [Teferi, Temporal Archmage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeferi%2c%20Temporal%20Archmage%5d) is your commander.  All you need is [The Chain Veil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThe%20Chain%20Veil%5d) and [Gilded Lotus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGilded%20Lotus%5d) on the battlefield (as well as 2 lands) and Teferi in the command zone.  This works because The Chain Veil activations apply to later instances of Teferi that will be cast, so by repeatedly killing him via his "-1" ability to untap The Chain Veil and your mana sources, and replaying him from the command zone, you are gaining more mana than you are spending on the extra commander tax.  As an added bonus, you get to draw your deck while doing this.

Also, credit to [@ArcanistLupus](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/43843/9999) for pointing out that an infinite turn combo in a deck with a shuffleback creature in your deck (such as [Emrakul, the Aeons Torn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEmrakul%2c%20the%20Aeons%20Torn%5d)) can technically be a replacement for a combo around The Chain Veil (it allows you to use the ultimate on a planeswalker with a non-lethal "+1" ability).  There exist two-card combos that do this, such as [Beacon of Tomorrows](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBeacon%20of%20Tomorrows%5d) and [Planar Portal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPlanar%20Portal%5d).

Comment: Note that Voltaic Construct only untaps artifact *creatures*

Comment: Voltaic Construct + Gilded Lotus isn't an infinite mana combo, and Voltaic Construct can't untap Chain Veil anyway.

Comment: @BenjaminCosman Whoops; I misremebered the ability.  This has been removed

Answer (score 7):

3 cards, in addition to the walker(s) you want to be hitting the ultimate of:

- [Tezzeret the Seeker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTezzeret%20the%20Seeker%5d)
- [The Chain Veil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThe%20Chain%20Veil%5d)
- [Everflowing Chalice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEverflowing%20Chalice%5d)

Chalice needs at least 4 counters, to pay for the veil, tezzeret +1 untaps both chalice and veil allowing infinite uses of veil which resets both tezzeret and the other walker(s), letting you rebuild the + abilities on those walkers until they ultimate again and again.

Comment: Plus lands to pay for them.

Comment: @Andrew Good answer.  Only works on planeswalkers with a +1 that doesn't kill your or your opponent though.

Comment: So, basically, those cards plust 8 mana are needed (8 mana for the 4 kicks of 2 each). With the 8 mana play chalice, use Tezzeret +1 untap chalice, produce 4 mana with chalice to pay for veil, use +1 to untap both, repeat

Comment: @DarkCygnus There are plenty of ways to cheat Everflowing Chalice up to 4 counters without actually paying the mana; I think leaving how to get those counters as an exercise for the reader is more prudent than trying to enumerate them, or worse, imply that mana is the only way to get it done.

Comment: @KRyan yes, this post does not ask "List the ways to play Everflowing Chalice", and as a MTG ignorant I am sure there are alternative ways to play it than depending solely on mana (perhaps one of those cards that +1s the number of counters on a card)

Comment: @Zags true, but no matter what you need a way to replace the counters, so you either flicker walkers that start able to ult, or reset the use of walkers with a plus, the second is much more common kind of walker.

Comment: @DarkCygnus Usually when talking combos you only refer to the cards involved in the combo itself in magic, not the cards it took to get them there, that would mean including mana to cast, the creatures and spells that protected the walkers until you could go off, tutors to find the walkers and artifacts involved, etc.

Answer (score 0):

### [Ajani, Wise Counselor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAjani%2c%20Wise%20Counselor%5d) with 10 loyalty counters, [Sage of Hours](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSage%20of%20Hours%5d), and at least 30 life.

Step one: Activate Ajani's ultimate, and place 30 +1/+1 counters on Sage of Hours.
Step two: Activate Sage of Hours and gain 6 additional turns.
Step three: Spend five turns adding counters to Ajani
Step four: Lather, rinse, repeat.

This isn't *technically* a recipe for infinite ultimates, because eventually you'll draw your entire deck and lose.  But that can be patched with a few ["When [Cardname] is put into a graveyard from anywhere, shuffle it into its owner's library." creatures](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[graveyard]+[shuffle]+[owner%27s]+[library]&type=+[%22Creature%22]) in your deck.  Just discard them for having >7 cards in hand, and your library becomes infinitely renewable.

[Time Vault](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTime%20Vault%5d) + anything that repeatedly untaps artifacts also works here, if you don't mind playing with a card banned or restricted in all formats (for this very reason)

Comment: I would admit that it's a three card combo instead of calling it a two card combo that requires a third card.

Comment: If we're going infinite turn combos, Beacon of Tomorrows + Planar Portal may be logistically simpler.

Comment: Also worth noting that this only works on planeswalkers with a "+1" ability that doesn't kill your or your opponent.

Comment: @zags Nexus of Fate instead of Beacon works too, or Panoptic Mirror and Time Warp (or any other extra turn spell that doesn't lose the game at end of turn) so long as it's not commander where mirror is banned.